# Using 'height:auto' for fullcalendar timeGridWeek view

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to have a completly visible fullcalendar week grid with no scrollbars. According to the document https://fullcalendar.io/docs/height I should set height to 'auto'. This will fit the grid and no scrollbars will not be visible. But doing this when using a timeGridWeek view, not all hours are accessabel.

I have created a little test application: https://codepen.io/olafxso/pen/LYZZmBN

In the test case you can see it has no scrollbars, but not all time slots are visible.

I allready discoverred that I could control it by changing some css:

```css
.fc .fc-timegrid-slot {
  height: 12px; /*This will change the actual timeslot height*/
}
.fc .fc-scrollgrid-section-body table {
  font-size: 1px; /** This allows me to make a timeslot smaller then the original font-size */
}
```

But changing the css font-size is not the way to go I think. Does anyone has got a better way for this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing directly to do with fullCalendar. It's the container you've placed it in which is the problem.

You've set the whole body to overflow:hidden, and then set the calendar's container to a fixed position whose boundaries are the edge of the viewport.

Unfortunately, especially in a CodePen (where the code takes up half the screen anyway), there physically isn't enough space to actually fit the calendar into the viewport, so it overflows downwards - but you've told CSS to make this area hidden.

If you simply get rid of all of these restrictions then it works fine - reduce your CSS to the following:

```
html, body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fc-header-toolbar {
  /*
  the calendar will be butting up against the edges,
  but let's scoot in the header's buttons
  */
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

The calendar itself then has no scrollbars (as per the documentation). Your overall page does, but that's only because the viewport isn't big enough to take the calendar. If you had a tall enough viewport then there would be no scrolling. You need to take into account the fact that different devices and browsers are different sizes!

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdErVow